# Bug in golang google protocol buffer

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a python program and a golang program both getting data from a socket. I print the bytes it receives from both.

```
python

Data = 0a300a084a6f686e20446f6510071a126a6f686e2e646f6540676d61696c2e636f6d220e0a0c3131312d3131312d31313130

golang

2016/04/02 23:21:08 50 bytes read from 192.168.0.1:65120
2016/04/02 23:21:08 00000000  0a 30 0a 08 4a 6f 68 6e  20 44 6f 65 10 08 1a 12  |.0..John Doe....|
00000010  6a 6f 68 6e 2e 64 6f 65  40 67 6d 61 69 6c 2e 63  |john.doe@gmail.c|
00000020  6f 6d 22 0e 0a 0c 31 31  31 2d 31 31 31 2d 31 31  |om"...111-111-11|
00000030  31 30                                             |10|
```

The .proto file is identical in both.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package MC_Feed;

message Person {
  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;  // Unique ID number for this person.
  string email = 3;

  message PhoneNumber {
    string number = 1;
    PhoneType type = 2;
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}

// Our address book file is just one of these.
message AddressBook {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

On the python (and C# for that matter) it works fine. On the golang side, I get this error:

```
2016/04/02 23:21:08 proto: MC_Feed.AddressBook: illegal tag 0 (wire type 0)
```

The go code is something I got from the net and modified a little:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
    "encoding/hex"
    "./Simple"
    "log"
    "net"
)

const (
    srvAddr         = "239.0.0.222:345"
    maxDatagramSize = 8192
)

func main() {
    serveMulticastUDP(srvAddr, msgHandler)
}


func msgHandler(src *net.UDPAddr, n int, b []byte) {
    log.Println(n, "bytes read from", src)
    log.Println(hex.Dump(b[:n]))
    newTest := &MC_Feed.AddressBook{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(b, newTest)
    log.Println(err)
}

func serveMulticastUDP(a string, h func(*net.UDPAddr, int, []byte)) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", a)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    l, err := net.ListenMulticastUDP("udp", nil, addr)
    l.SetReadBuffer(maxDatagramSize)
    for {
        b := make([]byte, maxDatagramSize)
        n, src, err := l.ReadFromUDP(b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("ReadFromUDP failed:", err)
        }
        h(src, n, b)
    }
}
```

Comment: As much of the Go code as you can give us would probably help. Unless someone is familiar with just what tends to cause that error message, it's hard to guess from this.

Comment: I added the go code to the post.

Comment: Don't know if this is all, but you need to `Unmarshal` only `b[:n]`, not all of `b`. I think you know, but `b` is long enough to hold the largest possible datagram; `b[:n]` is the part with real data.

Comment: @twotwotwo, thanks that is the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your buffer `b` is sized for the maximum possible datagram packet but not all of that is your message, only the first `n` bytes. The messages about `illegal tag 0` and `wire type 0` result from trying to parse the `0` bytes in buffer space you haven't otherwise initialized. Pass `b[:n]` to `Unmarshal` to fix.